# How can I access the /docs or custom routes end point while using fastapi as backend for supertokens?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I am using supertokens to build an authentication system and using fastApi as backend but while using their prebuild UI and already setup backend code in python, I am not able to access the 127.0.0.0:3000/docs endpoint. It is showing only a blank page.
Also, the custom routes that I have built in my API are not working and accessible.

Here is the code that I have written

```
@app.get("/sessioninfo")
async def secure_api(s: SessionContainer = Depends(verify_session())):
    return {
        "sessionHandle": s.get_handle(),
        "userId": s.get_user_id(),
        "accessTokenPayload": s.get_access_token_payload(),
    }
```

Here is the app_info part of **init** function in supertokens

```
app_info = InputAppInfo(
    app_name="demoApp",
    api_domain="http://localhost:3001",
    website_domain="http://localhost:3000",
)
```

After hitting the API with port 3000 and endpoint /sessioninfo I am getting blankpage
[localhost:3000/session_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR01a.png)

And for localhost:3001/session_info I am getting an internal server error.
[localhost:3001/session_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEfIU.png)

Answer (score -1):

localhost:3000/session_info won't respond with session info because it's being handled by the front end.

But localhost:3001/session_info should work. This error is likely to be happening because of python/dependency versions.

Update: As per [this GH comment](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/10743#issuecomment-1229022703), this error is likely to be coming from Python 3.11. So maybe try a different version of python

I hope this helps :)